# applying @font-face kits to joomla

Tags: css, joomla, fonts, font-face

I am having a bit of trouble with adding @font-face to joomla. I made the kits and added them to a .css file and had the template main page call it. In fact I know this communication is working because I have other css modifications there as well and they're working. But my new font "Duepuntozero" and "Philosopher" is not working in other computers other than my own.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and easy way is the declare the relative paths of the fonts on your server in the CSS file like so:

```
@font-face { /* declare fonts */
    font-family: "MuseoLight";
    src: url("fonts/Museo300-Regular.eot");
    src: local("Museo 300"), local("Museo-300"),
        url("fonts/Museo300-Regular.woff") format("woff"),
        url("fonts/Museo300-Regular.otf") format("opentype"),
        url("fonts/Museo300-Regular.svg#Museo-300") format("svg");
        }
        /* display fonts */
        h1 { font: 24px/1 MuseoLight, Verdana, sans-serif; }
        h2 { font: 18px/1 MuseoLight, Verdana, sans-serif; }
        h3 { font: 14px/1 MuseoLight, Verdana, sans-serif; }
```

Just change the above to mention Duepuntozero and Philosopher which I presume are .OTF font files according to dafont.com?

- Don’t nest different “@” selectors! Number one reason for failure is incorrect path names
- Refreshing, force-refreshing, and/or emptying your browser cache may help

If it's a case of only being available to view on your computer and no other computers, it is probably due to the fact that you've got your paths wrong, or the import declaration syntax is malformed

Comment: done! nothing yet. check my site [http://www.guhlmotors.com](http://www.guhlmotors.com) they look like regular verdana or georgia

Comment: @ReiBrazilva Which stylesheet can the font imports be found in?

Comment: Sorry, stupid question if you have, but have you actually uploaded these fonts?

Comment: well, not such a stupid question after all. No I haven't. Where in the directory would I do that in? I don't see a font folder

Comment: I'm not sure how your website is set up, but you will need to upload these via FTP to a folder that you specify (in your current css code, it is .../fonts/ I believe. If the fonts directory doesn't exist, you will need to create one. There are many many different FTP clients available, I suggest you use filezilla. You will need to know your website's IP address + the password

Comment: I have access to my files, I can create them manually within the server. I'm still unclear as to where exactly will be the right spot. I'm guessing somewhere within the template. But if at the time to declare its address in the css file, it will probably run into trouble. I'm used to working with static sites and Joomla is so messy it's killing my OCD

Comment: Easiest and quickest way to fix this is just to use an absolute URL i.e. `http://www.guhlmotors.com/fonts/font.otf` in your custom.css document, making sure that you create the fonts folder it is at that location

Comment: The paths of the fonts listed in the `tmp1.custom.css` file are still **relative** to the directory the CSS file is in. I took a look at the path of the tmp1.custom.css file and it is this: `http://www.guhlmotors.com/templates/as002035/css/tmpl.custom.css`. So either create a new "/fonts" folder in the `/css/` directory where the stylesheet `tmp1.custom.css` is (i.e. the path would be `http://www.guhlmotors.com/templates/as002035/css/fonts/font.otf`) or use an **absolute** path to the fonts folder in your CSS code i.e. `http://www.guhlmotors.com/fonts/duepuntozero.otf`

Comment: I downloaded the font files to the directory. Now, not even I can see the new fonts lol. Instead of making it so that everyone sees my new font, now I see what everyone else sees instead! any ideas? This lost me for sure

Comment: Alright I made a breakthrough! the path was wrong. And yes, you've been right all along. I knew you were right, I just couldn't figure out the path. Now the next issue is the font looks very messy! The letters are all different heights and just crazy looking. How do I fix that?

Comment: Never mind! Fixed it. Thanks adaam. You really helped me a lot

Comment: @ReiBrazilva That's okay, I'm glad to help.